# How to get one student from an SQL server DB using Java?

Tags: java, sql-server, database

I've been trying to get this code to work for several hours now and need some help. I have a database that contains a table called "Students". I'm trying to write the below method that selects one student based on user's input (which shall happen later in a gui). For now I am simply testing it in a Test class.

I want to get all the values of student in a 
`system.out.print`. What am I doing wrong?

```
public Student getOneSpecificStudent(int studentID) throws SQLException {

        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stm = null;

        try {
            con = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
            stm = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Student WHERE studentID = ?");
            stm.setInt(1, studentID);

            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();

            Student student = new Student();
            while (rs.next()) {
                return (new Student(studentID = rs.getInt("studentID"), rs.getString("studentSSN"), rs.getString("studentName"), rs.getString("studentAddress"), rs.getString("studentPhoneNumber")));

            }
            return student;
        } finally {
            DbUtils.close(con);
            DbUtils.close(stm);
        }
    }
```

My current problem is that this testmethod:

```
    try {
        dal.getOneSpecificStudent(2);
        System.out.println("Student is: " + student.getStudentSSN() + 
student.getStudentID() );
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL exception" + e );
    }
```

Returns null.

Comment: Within your testmethod you don't assign the result of `getOneSpecificStudent` to the `student` variable.

Comment: Check  student object contains value or you just create with new key word. would you please write full testmethod?

Comment: how and where do you initialize student object in test method?

Comment: in your select-statement the table is called student. In your intro you say that the tablename is students.

Comment: *"Returns null."* - What returns null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some rather "odd" code here:

```
    dal.getOneSpecificStudent(2);
    System.out.println("Student is: " + student.getStudentSSN() + 
                       student.getStudentID());
```

You are trying to call methods on a `student` variable ... but that's not related in any way to the previous statement.

1. The `getOneSpecificStudent(2)` call returns a value, but you are discarding it.
2. The `student` variable in the body of the `getOneSpecificStudent` method is a **local** variable.  It is not the same variable that you are printing.

So maybe your assertion that something *"Returns null"* should be reconsidered .....

Comment: Yup, I was initializing "Student student = new Student();" in my test file which meant I was returning nothing. Once I changed it to "Student student = dal.getOneSpecificStudent(2)"  I immediately got my values. Thank you very much for your help! Sometimes you truly are blind to your own mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this like:

> ```
> Student student = dal.getOneSpecificStudent(2);
> System.out.println("Student is: " + student.getStudentSSN() + 
> student.getStudentID() );
> ```

So it will print the values.

Answer (score 0):

So are you getting `null` values or you getting `NullPointerException`. If you are getting null values its because you are initialising your Student Object as empty in `Student student = new Student();` Since you haven't passed anything in the constructor. The student object is empty means getters will return null values.